# Javascript Calculate sum of all age in HTML form

Tags: javascript, html

I hava an HTML form that has 4 columns. The first two are First Name and Last Name. The Third is a HTML date, which receives the user Date of birth. The fourth one is the age that was generated from the HTML date of birth field.

The issue or problem here is I want to calculate the sum of all the age then display it in the HTML table, then also calculate the mean of all the age and display the result in HTML as well.

Observantly, everything else with the count is working and display, Except the sum of all the age and its mean.

Below is my HTML

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Date of Birth Registration</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/javascript"   href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/1.2.0/css/uikit.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/javascript" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/javascript" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/1.2.0/css/uikit.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/1.2.0/js/uikit.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src= "http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/1.2.0/js/uikit.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src= "http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="formiteration5.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="alert alert-success"><h1>Birth Registration</h1></div>
<hr />
<form id ="inputFrom" class="uk-form">
<label>First Name:
<input type='text' id='firstname'  value='' placeholder="" class="uk-form-success"/>
</label>
<label>Last Name:
<input type='text' id='lastname' placeholder="" class="uk-form-success"/>
</label>
<label for="size_1">D.O.B:</label><input type="date" name="size" id="birthDate" value="dd/mm/yy" laceholder="" class="uk-form-danger"/>
<input type='button' onclick='regBirth()' value='Add new person' class="uk-button-primary"/>
</form>
<hr />
<table id="details" class="uk-table uk-table-hover uk-table-striped uk-table-condensed">
<tr>
<th>First NameName</th>
<th>Last Name</th>
<th>Date of Birth</th>
<th>Age</th>
</tr> 
</table>

<h4>Statistics</h1>
<hr />
<div padding ="10px 10px 10px">
<div class="uk-grid">
<div class="uk-width-1-3">
<div class="uk-panel uk-panel-box-primary"><h4><br/>
email:m.cainton@gmail.com</p>

</div>
</div>
<div class="uk-width-1-3">
<div class="uk-panel uk-panel-box-primary"><h5><b>Total Count:</b></h5>
<p id="count"></p><h5><b>Sum:</b></h5>
<p name ="sum"id="sumofAge"></p></div>
</div>
<div class="uk-width-1-3">
<div class="uk-panel uk-panel-box-primary" ><h5><b>Mean:</b></h5>
<p id="meanAge"></p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Below is my Javascript

```
var allPeople = [];// global array
function regBirth() {


'use strict';
 // myArray should be instantiated as an object and not as an array
    var myObject = {};// empty object initialisation
    //var fname,lname,dob;
    myObject.fname = document.getElementById('firstname').value; //Object one
    myObject.lname = document.getElementById('lastname').value;//Object two
    myObject.dob = document.getElementById('birthDate').value;//Object three
    var dateOfBirth = new Date(myObject.dob);//Date of Birth
    var today = new Date();
    var dobYear = dateOfBirth.getFullYear();
    var dobMonth = dateOfBirth.getMonth() + 1;
    var dobDay = dateOfBirth.getDate();

    var myAge = Math.floor((today - dateOfBirth )/ 31557600000);
    myAge = document.getElementsByClassName("sum");
    var total = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < myAge.length; i++) {
        total += Number(myAge[i].value);
    }

    document.getElementById('sumofAge').value = total;

    console.log(myAge);
    //document.getElementById("age").innerHTML = myAge; 
    allPeople.push(myObject);
    console.log(allPeople.length);
    console.log(allPeople);
    // use var when you create tabularForm 
    var inputForm = document.getElementById("inputFrom").reset();
    var tabularForm = document.createDocumentFragment();
    var tablerow = document.createElement('tr'); 
    // iterate through the allPeople array
    // append to the dom the latest person (ie., myArray)
    var fname = document.createElement('td');//Start of First Name
    fname.innerHTML = myObject.fname;
    tablerow.appendChild(fname);//End of First Name

    var lname = document.createElement('td');//Start Lastname
    lname.innerHTML = myObject.lname;
    tablerow.appendChild(lname);//End Lastname

    var dob = document.createElement('td');//Start DOB
    dob.innerHTML = myObject.dob;
    tablerow.appendChild(dob);//End DOB

    var myBirthDay = document.createElement('td'); //Start of Birth Day
    myBirthDay.innerHTML = myAge;
    tablerow.appendChild(myBirthDay);//End of Birth Day

    tabularForm.appendChild(tablerow); 
    document.getElementById("details").appendChild(tabularForm);  

    var totalPeople = allPeople.length; //Start Count
    document.getElementById("count").innerHTML=totalPeople; // Count declaration
}
```

Comment: Any error messages in the console?

Comment: ReferenceError:total is undefined...thats the error

Comment: When I also tried to find your error, a found an error. The calculation of the age is wrong. The result is for one year smaller. don't forget to check it.

Comment: Because it base on the day not the month..For example, if birthdate was 23/03/1980 and today is 19/03/2014, though it is now 34 years, I am still 33 years because I have not yet reach 23 of March...Iam 34 when I enter the date of 23/03/2014

Comment: My age and my family was one year smaller^^

Answer (score 0):

myAge is first used as a number and then as an array, I think that might cause you some problems... This makes more sense:

```
var myAge = Math.floor((today - dateOfBirth) / 31557600000);
var sum = document.getElementsByClassName("sum");
var total = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < sum.length; i++) {
     total += Number(sum[i].value);
}
```

Comment: Addationaly the second error is, that no element with css class 'sum' does not exists.

Comment: so where does sum gets its value from?

Comment: @IslandKing according to your javascript code there should be elements with class "sum" where the sum variable are supposed to get its values from. However, you don't have any such elements in you HTML.

Comment: @IslandKing The real reason for your error is, that you try to sum up a value with a null value.

Comment: What about doing this
 var sum = myAge;
    var total = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < sum.length; i++) {
        total += Number(sum[i].value);
    }